# UICollectionViewCell size animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am using a UICollectionView with 2 columns in it. i have a requirement to resize (expand) a cell when it is tapped. Im using the following bit of code which seems to be working except that the whole row gets expanded instead of a single cell... Im sure there must be a way to avoid using UICollectionView,dont want to use two seperate tableviews just coz of this minor problem..

PFB the code that im using to adjust the size of the cell..

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CGSize itemSize;

    if([self.selectedOrder isEqual:indexPath]) {

        NSLog(@"coming");
     itemSize = (CGSize ){.width = 330, .height = 150};

    }
    else {

    itemSize = (CGSize ){.width = 330, .height = 75};

    }

    return itemSize;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if([self.selectedOrder isEqual:indexPath]) {

        self.selectedOrder = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:-1 inSection:-1];
    }
    else {

        self.selectedOrder = indexPath;

    }
    [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        // append your data model to return a larger size for
        // cell at this index path
       // [collectionView invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
        [collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
        [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];

}
```

Comment: im not using a customFlowLayout.. If it is required ,please guide me on what methods needs to be implemented in it.. Unfortunately i cant add the screenshot of how it looks since im a newbie to this site..